# How can I get the "What's Up, Doc?" hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

> **What's Up, Doc?** : earn reputation by contributing to Stack Overflow
>   documentation

Does this mean that I can get this hat:

- if I have already contributed to Stack Overflow documentation before and get some reputation in this period
- or do I have contribute now and get some reputation for the new contribution?

Or what exactly do I have to do?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I just got it after a `+1` on a existing topic I haven't touched in months.

So, you don't need to actively contribute to docs to get it.

Comment: It's harder to have contributed than to contribute, though.

Comment: @DenysSéguret, that depends on your personal situation. For some user's it is *much* easier to have contributed than to contribute.

Comment: Yes, I *have contributed* and therefore earned the hat. It is, however, *impossible* for me to contribute, since I am no longer using Documentation until there are massive changes made. Like a purge.

Comment: @CodyGray: It's not ___impossible___ for you to contribute. You just refuse to. Subtle difference.